# Provider is notifying listeners but not sending data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

As the title says, the provider is notifying the listeners but not sending the data.
How do i know it is notifying ? Because debugging breakpoints in the screen do activate after the `notifyListeners()`. The `weatherOfToday` in the provider is receiving the data from the call, but somehow it get stuck there and doesn't get to the screen.

this is the provider>

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/exthernal/models/first_call_model.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/exthernal/models/w_response_model.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/exthernal/w_service.dart';

class WeatherProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  WeatherService firtCaller = WeatherService();
  WeatherService weatherCall = WeatherService();
  FirstCallModel firstCall = FirstCallModel();
  WeatherResponseModel weatherOfToday = WeatherResponseModel();

  weatherCaller() async {
    var firstCall = await firtCaller.getFirstCall();
    var weatherOfToday = await weatherCall.getHttp();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

this is the screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/logic/w_provider.dart';

class WeatherToday extends StatelessWidget {
  const WeatherToday({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => WeatherProvider(),
        child: Consumer<WeatherProvider>(
            builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: value.weatherCaller,
                            child: const Text('call')),
                        Text(value.weatherOfToday.nombre ?? 'empty')
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )));
  }
}
```

let me know if i omitted any key information.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weatherOfToday` is not changed when `weatherCall.getHttp()` is called, instead the local variable is assigned.

```
WeatherResponseModel weatherOfToday = WeatherResponseModel();

weatherCaller() async {
  // var weatherOfToday = await weatherCall.getHttp();
  weatherOfToday = await weatherCall.getHttp();
  notifyListeners();
}
```